# Counter instance method with inner class

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, static-methods, python-decorators

I'm building a function pipeline and I need know how many class instance is opened for indexing each function,
also I need to set 'Start' param for init the counter to 0 as it handle run many time the same pipeline without have the count increasing above the limit.

First at all I build a method which is working well with only one pipeline, as the Counter  is shared with each other pipeline class

```
class Foo3():
    class Counter:
        def __init__(self,func):
            self.counter = 0
            self.func = func
            #Counter.method  =method
        def __call__(self,*args, **kwds):
            self.counter += 1
            return self.func(*args, **kwds)



    #count= Counter()
    string = 'this is '
    start = True

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        #self.method = method
        self.ainit(self)
        self.newinst()
        print(self.newinst.counter)
    @Counter
    def newinst():
        pass
    @classmethod
    def ainit(cls,inst):
        print(cls.string +inst.name)

    @classmethod
    def getCount(cls,inst):
        print(self.newinst.counter) 

class pipe1(Foo3):
    pass
class pipe2(Foo3):
    pass 
pipe1('test')
pipe1('test2')
pipe1('test3')
pipe2('test_new')
```

output

```
this is test
1
this is test2
2
this is test3
3
this is test_new
4
```

Now I try to figure out how pass a start method within the Counter Class in the purpose to indicate where pipe line start.
But my solution is not working because I try to use @static method in a wrong way

```
class Foo3():
    class Counter:
        method = 'regular'
        def __init__(self,func,method:str='regular' ):
            self.counter = 0
            self.func = func
            Counter.method  =method
        def __call__(self,method,*args, **kwds):
            if Counter.method == 'Start':
                print('count = 0')
                self.counter = 0
            if Counter.method == 'regular' :  
                print('+1')
                self.counter += 1
            return self.func(*args, **kwds)

    #count= Counter()
    string = 'this is '
    start = True
    @Counter
    @staticmethod
    def newinst(method='regular'):
        pass
    def __init__(self, name, method:str='regular'):
        self.name = name
        self.method = method
        print(self.ainit(self))
        Foo3.newinst(method)
        print(self.newinst.counter)

    @classmethod
    def ainit(cls,inst):
        print(cls.string +inst.name)

    @classmethod
    def getCount(cls,inst):
        print(self.newinst.counter)
```

If I used a counter Class as solution it's because I want one count per Pipeline

```
class pipe1(Foo3):
    pass
class pipe2(Foo3):
    pass    


pipe1('test', 'Start')
pipe1('test2')
pipe1('test3')
pipe2('test_new', 'Start')
pipe1.getCount()
pipe2.getCount()
```

output expected :

```
this is test

1
this is test2
2
this is test3
3
this is test_new
1
3
1
```

but i get as issue :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-440-1710b9b56152> in <module>
     54 
     55 if __name__ == "__main__":
---> 56     Foo3('a')

<ipython-input-440-1710b9b56152> in __init__(self, name, method)
     43         self.name = name
     44         self.method = method
---> 45         Foo3.newinst(method)
     46         print(self.newinst.counter)
     47 

<ipython-input-440-1710b9b56152> in __call__(self, method, *args, **kwds)
     29                 print('+1')
     30                 self.counter += 1
---> 31             return self.func(*args, **kwds)
     32 
     33 

TypeError: 'staticmethod' object is not callable
```

Comment: "If I used a nested class as solution it's because I want one count per Pipeline" How does the first relate to the second? You are creating only one ``Counter`` instance for every single instance one very single class that does not replace ``Counter.__init__``.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue with the code shown. Nesting ``Counter`` like this is not valid, because ``Counter`` is a class variable that is not visible in the nested scope of ``Foo3.Counter.__init__`` and the other methods. This means the code already fails at the line ``@Counter``.

Comment: Note that ``newinst`` should not be declared a staticmethod since it is passed to ``Counter`` as a function, and then replaced by the ``Counter`` instance. It is never used as a method.

Comment: I could not use it but I meet issue about self and cls otherwise, if I remove static method, it is work but I didn't manage to use the 'Start' parameter

Comment: Well, your code has multiple issues, such as ``ainit`` being declared a class method but expecting an instance, ``getCount`` using ``self`` but not receiving it, ``Counter`` applying to all pipelines, and perhaps some more. It is very much unclear what you are trying to do, and as such how to help you. Please consult the [How to Ask help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to formulate a question with a clear problem statement that we can actually answer.

Comment: You are right I edited my post, First at all I would know is there are a way figure out my issue in my own way.
 I edited in such a way as to let you know an other solution without keeping my structure, you can run the first solution but there are no 'Start' method anymore, maybe you have a better idea to implement it

Comment: I find a solution for the first problem but not for the second that is make working the `getCount` function.
I would not have to specify informations in `pipeline1` and `pipeline2`, and make it work all by inheritance of `Foo3`.
If I put out the `Counter` class, and open instance as `global`parameter of `Foo3`  it will be common to all `pipeline` , how make it specifi to each other ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211294/discussion-between-chrys-bltr-and-mistermiyagi).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a solution

```
class Foo3():
    class Counter:

        method = 'regular'
        def __init__(self,func, method= 'regular'):
            self.counter = 0
            self.func = func
            #print(method)
            Counter.method  =method
            #print(Counter.method)
        def __call__(self,*args,method ='regular', **kwds):

            if method == 'Start':
                self.counter =0
            elif method =='regular':
                self.counter += 1
            else :
                raise Exception("this method doesn't exist")
            return self.func(*args, **kwds)



    #count= Counter()
    string = 'this is '
    start = True
    @Counter
    def newinst(method='regular'):
        pass
    def __init__(self, name, method= 'regular'):
        self.name = name
        #self.method = method
        self.ainit(self)
        self.newinst(method=method)
        print(self.newinst.counter)

    @classmethod
    def ainit(cls,inst):
        print(cls.string +inst.name)

    @classmethod
    def getCount(cls,inst):
        print(self.newinst.counter)
```

output

```
class pipe1(Foo3):
    pass
class pipe2(Foo3):
    pass    
pipe1('test', 'Start')
pipe1('test2')
pipe1('test3')
pipe2('test_new','Start')

this is test
0
this is test2
1
this is test3
2
this is test_new
0
```

My error came from my weak knowledge  about `decorator` and inner `Class`, in my exemple , the `__init__` fonction of Counter is instanciate even before I build a pipeline, then I didn't figure out how pass 'Start' in parameter as I set it in the **init** function.
Now my other problem - as @MisterMiyagi mentionned - come from the fact that my  `getCount()`function shouldn't work and I better  to keep out the Counter class, but I didn't still figuring out how open one `Counter` instance per `pipeline` with inheritance of `Foo3` without specify it in the `pipline Class global' parameter.